# Copy constructor implicitly called?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, copy-elision

I have the following class with both a normal constructor and copy constructor defined.

```
#include <iostream>

class Bla
{
public:
    Bla()
    {
        std::cout << "Normal Constructor Called\n";
    }

    Bla(const Bla& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor Called\n";
    }

};

int main() 
{
    Bla a = Bla(); // prints Normal Constructor
}
```

In the main function, it prints the normal constructor as I expected and only the normal constructor. However, if I make the copy constructor a private member of the class, the compiler gives me the error

```
error: ‘Bla::Bla(const Bla&)’ is private within this context
```

From the looks of it, it looks like the copy constructor was called, but I do not see anything being printed from it. Is the copy constructor being implicitly called? What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before C++17, the copy operation might be [elided](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) but the copy constructor still needs to be present and accessible.

> This is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy`/move (since C++11)` constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed:

Since C++17 there's no such issue because of mandatory copy elision.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:

Comment: I see now. Just for a sanity check, I compiled my project against C++17 and it worked just like you said. Thanks for the help.